# LM338 with pass transistors

Tags: voltage-regulator, high-current

[image]

Looking for formulas for figuring out R1,R9,R10. The transistors and regulator is what I have on-hand. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This circuit makes me cringe every time I see it. Putting in those extra pass transistors completely bypasses the regulators internal thermal and short circuit protection. The LM338 is a 5A regulator. If you need more current than that, it's time to be looking at switching regulators.

Comment: Totally true, it's how we did things in the 1970s ;-) Still this one is nicer on a cold day in winter as you can warm your hands with it ;-) I agree that a switched (buck) converter module would be a more modern choice.

Answer (score 3):

Short and useless answer: you only need Ohm's law and maybe \$Ib = Ic/beta\$ for the base current of the transistors.

A bit less useless answer:

Instead of concentrating on which formulas you need, first ask yourself: what happens ? Then it will become clear what formulas to apply.

R1 is across base-emitter of Q1 so I would expect a voltage of 0.7 V (roughly) across R1. Current ? The current at which Q2 - Q5 need to "kick-in", say 100 mA: 0.7/0.1 = 7 ohms. Ha ! I only used Ohm's law :-)

R9, R10 see how these are a voltage divider setting the voltage at the bases of all those 2N3055. The higher that voltage, the more voltage drop you get arcross the 4 0.1 ohm resistors. So determine how much voltage you want across these: take the maximum current, divide by 4 (4 resistors). Then calculate the voltage across them. Add about 0.8 - 1 Volt for the VBEs of Q2-Q5 (look in the datasheet what VBE will be at the current they will conduct).

Now you know the voltage across R10. Output voltage is 13.8 V, input is 24 V so roughly 10.2 V across VCE of Q1 and R9 and R10. We know voltage across R10 so leaves us voltage across VCE of Q1 and R9. I would split that so that Q1 has a couple of volts to work with. Q1 and R9 also need to supply the base currents for Q2-Q5 which can be significant (2N3055 have a low beta).

Draw it on a piece of paper and start annotationg some values. You don't have to be 100% correct the first time. Just fill in values to see what works.

Comment: Thank you so very much.  Was using max values from datasheets. This is to restore an old 1960's power supply that had popped the voltage regulator (CA 3085A) and Q1 (BD439) transistor. I bread boarded the LM338 and all worked as per datasheet. 

From the datasheets I downloaded, here is some of the Max values:
2N5194  hFE = 25 -100 @ IC = 1.5 Adc
Vbe = 5 V
Vce = 60 V

2N3055  hFE = 20−70 @ IC = 4 Adc
Vbe = 7 V
Vce = 60 V

Not sure I understand how the low Beta effects the base currents of Q2-5. Or the Beta of Q1 has on the bases of Q2-5?

Comment: The low beta of Q2-5: suppose the beta is 10 that means that the base current (supplied by Q1) is 1/10 of the output current of this circuit. So if you load it with 5 Amps, 0.5 Amps (total for Q2-5) are needed to drive Q2-Q5. SO Q1 needs to supply this and this also flows through R9. Most transistors have a high beta, like more than 100, the 2N3055 do not so the base current you need can be significant. That's why I mentioned that.

Comment: The beta of Q1 is unrelated to those of Q2-5 and also high enough, you can assume that the base current of Q1 is small. The current through R1 will be much larger than Q1's base current so you can safely ignore that base current.